# Converting a String to a Splittable in GWT

Tags: gwt, autobean

I'm maintaining a site written in GWT (2.5.0) that is used internally by our development team, and I've been experimenting with using AutoBeans for client side json parsing. I have a few objects with json that is not well defined — a developer can dump whatever json string he wants in there — so I'm using a Splittable property. In order to support editing this arbitrary json I'd like to convert a String into a Splittable, but I haven't found a straight-forward way of accomplishing this. Do I need to implement this interface myself or resort to something hacky like wrapping the json in another json object I can then decode into a throw-away AutoBean just to get a Splittable of the original json?

Answer (score 1):

`StringQuoter` is the utility class which we do much of our manual Splittable work with.

Just user `StringQuoter.create("some string");` to produce a `Splittable` whose payload is

```
"some string"
```

Once you have that splittable, you can assign it to a key in another splittable with the following method:

```
Splittable.assign(Splittable parent, String propertyName);
```

However, if you are trying to convert some arbitrary string which contains a JSON structure into a splittable, use `StringQuoter.split(..)` to create it. The resulting splittable can be queried as normal (i.e. what keys exist/don't exist, etc).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your response. I haven't tried this in production mode, but in development mode if I pass a json String StringQuoter.split and pass the resulting splittable to AutoBeanCodex.decode I get a TargetInvocationException, "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/WeakMapping".  Thoughts?